# Magento SOAP API V2 with C#: Issue with Stores that Require HTTP Authentication 

Tags: c#, xml, magento

REVISED QUESTION
I have revised the original question (as seen below) so that I can mark a part of the problem as answered.  So here goes:
I have built a tool to import sales orders from customer stores (magento) for integration into our legacy order processing system.  I have five stores to import from.   One of them has HTTP Authentication set on its store and my API Login fails because of this.  How do I get past this?

ORIGINAL QUESTION (Title: Importing Sales Orders from Magento Using C#: There is an error in XML document (2, 372)):

I have built a tool to import sales orders from customer stores (magento) for integration into our legacy order processing system.  I have five stores to import from.   Three work fine.

- PROBLEM 1: The fourth store throws up this exception upon executing
  the salesOrderList() call:

  > A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
  >
  > There is an error in XML document (2, 372).

  The login succeeds, I am able to enumerate attribute values, etc. 
  But I am unable to run the `salesOrderList()` function with any
  filter (and `null` too).  It would be great if someone has experience
  with this and can point me in the right direction.
- PROBLEM 2: The fifth store has **HTTP authorization** to access its
  main magento page. I have only worked with API User Name and API Key.
  But it looks like I have to cross the HTTP Authorization hurdle to
  get to the API login stage. The `Login()` function of magento web
  service takes only the API User Name and API Key. Not sure how to
  handle the extra layer of HTTP Authentication. Can anyone help?

Comment: What component are you using, or you are parsing everything by your own? what api version are you using? did you simple add the api v.2 url and import as web reference? btw, extra authentication, normally is placed in the `header` of your request.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, Cody/balexandre.  I am not using any component.  Just raw C# with Magento SOAP API V2.  

Yes, the V2 URL suffix has been added and it does work well for three sites.  

The fourth site throws exception when invoking salesOrderList() but works fine with other calls like (say) catalogProductAttributeOptions().  

The fifth store has HTTP authentication and so I always end up with "Authorization Required" error despite having full API Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen often, you just got lucky and it's the first time you're having this problem.

What you can do is using **fiddler** verify why are you receiving a bad XML format, as .NET only parses it and sees that Magento did not sent anything that is worth of trying as it's wrongly created.

Normally you end up parsing the raw responses from Magento as it's way safer, or use XmlRpc calls.

But for now, check as you have more than one to test, the difference between the responses in fiddler.

Regarding your authentication, you need to ask the host for the credentials, and add them to your request as a new `NetworkCredentials` object in the correct property of your service object.

Comment: Your advice regarding NetworkCredentials was spot on (though unfortunbately that store is also throwing up the XML Error exception now)!  As I do not have enough "reputation score" to upvote you, I have split the question into two and am marking this post as "answered".  Will post the link to the other question shortly.  Thanks balexandre!

Comment: Okay - the unresolved "XML Error" part of the question has been moved to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741095/importing-sales-orders-from-magento-using-c-sharp-salesorderlist-function-th.