# Importing Sales Orders from Magento Using C# (salesOrderList function): "There is an error in XML document (2, 372)"

Tags: c#, xml, magento, soap

Note: This question was originally part of [Magento SOAP API V2 with C#: Issue with Stores that Require HTTP Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739640/magento-soap-api-v2-with-c-issue-with-stores-that-require-http-authentication)  but I have moved a part of it here as a new question, as one part was already answered on that post.
ISSUE: 
I have built a tool to import sales orders from customer stores (magento) for integration into our legacy order processing system.  I have five stores to import from.   Three work fine.  Two of them have the following problem:

- The following Exception is thrown upon executing the `salesOrderList()` call:

  > A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
  >
  > There is an error in XML document (2, 372).

  The login succeeds, I am able to enumerate attribute values, etc. 
  But I am unable to run the `salesOrderList()` function with any
  filter (and `null` too).  It would be great if someone has experience
  with this and can point me in the right direction, please.

**Update:** The invoking call is as follows:

```
salesOrderEntity[] soe = mservice.salesOrderList(mlogin, objSalesOrderFilterSet);
```

The Exception is, *There is an error in XML document (2, 372).*
The InnerException is, *The specified type was not recognized: name='salesOrderListEntity', namespace='urn:Magento', at .*

**Fiddler** showed the following requested and returned for the salesOrderList() call:
Requested:

```
POST /api/v2_soap/index HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.239)
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPoz6RG9JzwkdBniF95/gqmAcAAAAAhgJHnbvB1UOTE1y4R1Iq5VGLcSLUxTNDg57BO/4OizgACQAA
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerAction"
Host: www.contoso.com
Content-Length: 1753
Expect: 100-continue
```

Returned:

```
    POST http://www.contoso.com/api/v2_soap/index HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.239)
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPoz6RG9JzwkdBniF95/gqmAcAAAAAhgJHnbvB1UOTE1y4R1Iq5VGLcSLUxTNDg57BO/4OizgACQAA
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerAction"
Host: www.contoso.com
Content-Length: 1753
Expect: 100-continue

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:Magento" xmlns:types="urn:Magento/encodedTypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><tns:salesOrderList><sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">2f9c5bdc898fd92c1f61981147ee5495</sessionId><filters href="#id1" /></tns:salesOrderList><tns:filters id="id1" xsi:type="tns:filters"><complex_filter href="#id2" /></tns:filters><soapenc:Array id="id2" soapenc:arrayType="tns:complexFilter[3]"><Item href="#id3" /><Item href="#id4" /><Item href="#id5" /></soapenc:Array><tns:complexFilter id="id3" xsi:type="tns:complexFilter"><key xsi:type="xsd:string">created_at</key><value href="#id6" /></tns:complexFilter><tns:complexFilter id="id4" xsi:type="tns:complexFilter"><key xsi:type="xsd:string">created_at</key><value href="#id7" /></tns:complexFilter><tns:complexFilter id="id5" xsi:type="tns:complexFilter"><key xsi:type="xsd:string">status</key><value href="#id8" /></tns:complexFilter><tns:associativeEntity id="id6" xsi:type="tns:associativeEntity"><key xsi:type="xsd:string">from</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-12-28 00:00:00</value></tns:associativeEntity><tns:associativeEntity id="id7" xsi:type="tns:associativeEntity"><key xsi:type="xsd:string">to</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">2011-12-28 23:59:59</value></tns:associativeEntity><tns:associativeEntity id="id8" xsi:type="tns:associativeEntity"><key xsi:type="xsd:string">in</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">processing</value></tns:associativeEntity></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2012 12:11:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.20 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.6
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Content-Length: 6302
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:salesOrderListResponse><result SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:salesOrderListEntity[1]" xsi:type="ns1:salesOrderListEntityArray"><item xsi:type="ns1:salesOrderListEntity"><increment_id xsi:type="xsd:string">100001306</increment_id><store_id 
...<more data>...
xsi:type="xsd:string">John</firstname><lastname xsi:type="xsd:string">Doe</lastname><telephone xsi:type="xsd:string">999-999-9999 ext. 3333</telephone><postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">11111</postcode></item></result></ns1:salesOrderListResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: can you copy/paste the document from **fiddler** so we can see the output? will be hard to help you without seeing the output...

Comment: Yes, I will certainly do that.  In the meantime, can you please post your earlier fiddler advice as an answer here so that I can "accept" it as an answer if this effort succeeds?  Thanks.

Comment: No. Give us the document so we help you better, just telling you to check [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) should not be an acceptable answer... just open fiddler and your project in `localhost`, then make the call and see what's going on in the HTTP protocol, check what are you asking and what are you receiving...

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  I have pasted the file from fiddler, minus the customer data.  It does seem to return the data correctly but the call throws the XML Error exception as described, rendering all data inaccessible via the Magento SOAP V2 object model.

Comment: are the API's from the other store the same Magento versions? or some are 1.4, some 1.5 or 1.6...?... there are problems between them as you can read on every version details

Comment: No.  The stores that work are v1.6 and one of the stores that don't work is v1.5.1.  Looks like there is significant discrepancy between salesOrderEntity[] and salesOrderListEntity[] returned by the salesOrderList() function.  Would tweaking Reference.cs to "accept" both types be a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay, here goes.  The service reference in the original program was created by pointing to a `wsdl` address under one of our Magento Go stores.  The program allowed dynamically changing the shop to work with, and so the URL was changed to the relevant shop URL appended with `/api/v2_soap/index` at runtime.

As explained in the question, the sales order import worked for some sites and failed for others.   After some pretty good advice by balexandre, we used **fiddler** and some on-the-spot code as needed and figured out the issue.

**The Problem Was:** The service call `salesOrderList()` returns salesOrderEntity[] for **Magento Go** shops and `salesOrderListEntity[]` for 1.5.x shops.  As the proxy was created using a Magento Go reference, the latter type was "unexpected" for the program, thereby causing the `Exception` *There is an error in XML document (2, 372)* with the `innerException` *The specified type was not recognized: name='salesOrderListEntity', namespace='urn:Magento'*.  All the other methods that we had invoked from the web service worked though.  But without sales order listing, they weren't much useful on their own.

**An Intermediate Workaround Was:** To tweak the `wsdl` file and `reference.cs` to declare 'salesOrderListEntity`and to create an overloaded version of`salesOrderListEntity()`.  But this workaround created more problems than it solved.

**The Final Solution Is:** Create two different proxies by pointing to Magento Go and Magento 1.5.x.  After switching to the actual shop URLs at runtime, use the proxy relevant for the current shop.  Same calls and flow, except that the first proxy knows that it will receive `salesOrderEntity[]` for a `salesOrderList()` call and the second proxy knows that it will receive `salesOrderListEntity[]`.

This works without issues and we have imported a few hundred sales orders as I write this.  And it seems to work well for 1.6.1 shops as well.  But I shall let you know if (God forbid) there be any issues on that front.

On a concluding note, my sincere thanks to balexandre for all the help extended.

Answer (score 1):

This has an easy fix, though it might take some time and you need to change some code.

**The problem:** You can't use the Magento WSDL address if not less than 1.6.0, as it contains weird bugs that are fixed only with 1.6, read the [release notes of each version](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes#Release%20Notes%20-%20Magento%201.6.1.0%20%28Oct%2019,%202011%29) for more information

**The Solution:** Remove all Service References from your project and create a proxy using the `svcutil.exe` utility pointing to a `wsdl` address that is from the most recent Magento (even if you install the latest version just for this, the latest stable to this date is 1.6.1).

Then add that generated project to your web/win project and use the service from it, and swap the final url in the Client object, for example:

```
MyNameSpace.MagentoSoapClient ws = new MyNameSpace.MagentoSoapClient();
ws.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://domain.com/api/v2_soap");
```

give that a try.

Comment: Hi, thanks again.  The original program itself was written that way because we had to switch URLs at runtime.  The difference was that the proxy was created by pointing to a Magento Go URL.  But after going through the fiddler file (as you had suggested), I could see that while the salesOrderList() call to the Magento Go shops returned salesOrderList[], the same call to 1.5.x returned salesOrderListEntity[] causing the exception.  I have now added a service reference using the other shop as well, and switching between the two proxies at runtime as needed.  It works.  Thanks again for the help.